# Estimating Ethernet line length

Tags: networking, switch-statement, aruba

I'm trying to write a Network Visualization tool for HP/Aruba Switches and now confronted with the Question how to estimate the Length of a Connnection?

For Fibre Trancievers you can get some Info using

```
show interfaces transceiver <port> detail
```

This gives me this:

```
Transceiver in A22
   Interface Index    : 22  
   Type               : SFP+LR          
   Model              : J9151A  
   Connector Type     : LC                              
   Wavelength         : 1310nm                          
   Transfer Distance  : 10.0km (9um),                                   
   Diagnostic Support : DOM   
   Serial Number      : <bla>      

 Status
   Temperature : 37.511C         
   Voltage     : 3.2492V         
   Tx Bias     : 36.514mA        
   Tx Power    : 0.6053mW, -2.180dBm     
   Rx Power    : 0.3652mW, -4.375dBm     

  Time Stamp    : Mon Jan 31 09:23:12 2022
```

The Question is: Is it realistically possible to judge the Length of the line using the Tx/Rx Power Values?
I know that the SNR on a line is dependant on all kind of factors (fibre quality, number of splices / connections on the way etc.) - but is it realistic to hit a somewhat crude estimate with those number?

Are there better tools to do this? Maybe some LLDP function?

kind regards